# What is the relation between bandwidth and resolution?

Tags: resolution, streaming, bandwidth, video-streaming

I want to encode a video in DASH format. I want to have multiple bitrate/bandwidth with multiple resolution. I'm still wondering:

- What is relationship between bandwidth and resolution? For example: bandwidth 1.7Mbps with 1280x720 and 1.1Mbps with 1280x720. Can we see the different?
- Is there any guidelines on what resolution should be for each bandwidth constraint? From the highest to the lowest.

Thanks,

Comment: resolution is pretty much a "limit" of quality, while the bitrate is the actual quality (assuming the original has higher quality than what the target bitrate of the target codec can provide)

Comment: Quality per bitrate (if we for a second pretend that "quality" is a quantity that can be objectively quantified and specified as some kind of single value, which in reality it is not) is also very heavily dependent on which codec you are using. *For a given codec, at a given resolution*, higher bitrates *usually* mean better quality, where the difference may or may not be perceptible, but once you start comparing different codecs the situation is nowhere near as clear-cut.